# Two NICs, adding default route

Tags: networking

I have an ubuntu 16.04LTS (dekstop) machine with two network cards. One is attached to a cable modem, let's call that IP address 77.77.77.77. The other is attached to a router *which has no internet connectivity* and I don't want it to. The second NIC has a VLAN address like 192.168.1.150

When CAT6 cables are connected to BOTH NICs, I cannot get any internet access. It looks like ubuntu is trying to route all traffic through the VLAN IP. I want to tell the O/S to route ONLY the VLAN traffic through the router and everything else to the second network card which has real internet access.

I am aware that this requires some setting of routes, but I am not that familiar with that level of networking. Any help? TIA!

PS: using gnome-shell and allowing all networking to go through that rather than mucking with /etc/network/interfaces which contains only this:

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: With a Desktop installation, Network Manager controls your Internet.  YOu'd have to do all the configuration in Network Manager (rather than using `/etc/network/interfaces`).  Set a gateway for only the first address, then static-set the second NIC to an IP address you want it to have and don't give it a gateway; that should then use only the first NIC for the Internet.

Comment: Can you share the output of `ip route show` command?

Comment: Thomas Ward's suggestion fixed it. I changed the IPV4 settings on the VLAN card to manual, left the "default gateway" field blank, saved, disconnected the cable and reconnected it and now I have internet and call still access IPs on the VLAN. THanks!

Comment: You or @ThomasWard could add the solution as an answer to this question to help others...